# Sum a List, but only for values after a certain point

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing a web page to keep the score for a card game. Getting the players score so far would be easy, but there is a twist. During any round the players score can be reset to zero at the start of the round. I don't want to change the score for any previous rounds, so I only want to get a sum of the rounds after (and including) the reset. A player could potentially have their score reset multiple times in a game, or not at all.

I can get the correct score by a multiple stage process of finding the last (if any) score reset, and summing all hands after that (or all hands in no resets) - see PlayerGame.GetPlayerScore.

I'm still trying to get my head around the more intricate ways of doing things with LINQ, and I was wondering if there was a way to do this using a single LINQ statement?

Minimal code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PlayerGame playerGame = new PlayerGame();

        playerGame.PlayerHands = new List<PlayerHand>
        {
            new PlayerHand { Round = 1, Score = 10 },
            new PlayerHand { Round = 2, Score = 20 },
            new PlayerHand { Round = 3, Score = 30 },
            new PlayerHand { Round = 4, Score = 40, Reset = true },
            new PlayerHand { Round = 5, Score = 50 },
            new PlayerHand { Round = 6, Score = 60 }
        };

        Console.WriteLine($"Players score was {playerGame.GetPlayerScore()}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class PlayerHand
{
    public int Round { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public bool Reset { get; set; } = false;
}

class PlayerGame
{
    public List<PlayerHand> PlayerHands { get; set; }

    public PlayerGame()
    {
        PlayerHands = new List<PlayerHand> { };
    }

    public int GetPlayerScore()
    {
        // Can all this be simplified to a single LINQ statement?
        var ResetIndex = PlayerHands.OrderBy(t => t.Round).LastOrDefault(t => t.Reset == true);

        if (ResetIndex != null)
        {
            return PlayerHands.Where(t => t.Round >= ResetIndex.Round).Sum(t => t.Score);
        }
        else
        {
            return PlayerHands.Sum(t => t.Score);
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/s5rSqJ

As presented, the players score should be 150. I.e. the score gets reset at the start of Round 4, so the total score is the sum of Rounds 4, 5, and 6.

Comment: Btw, why you use `PlayerHands.OrderBy(t => t.Round).LastOrDefault(..)` instead of `PlayerHands.OrderByDescending(t => t.Round).FirstOrDefault(....)`? The latter is more efficient

Comment: The default value of `bool` is false, so the assignment of `public bool Reset { get; set; } = false;` is redundant.

Comment: is your `Round` contain values in sequencial manner?

Comment: @Tim, there was no particular reason for doing OrderBy...LastOrdefault. This is just a quick minimal sample.

Comment: @Chriz, you're right, but it has no bearing on the point of the question.

Comment: @Prasad, yes, the values for Round should always be sequential.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, just out of interest I did a performance comparison between OrderBy...LastOrDefault and OrderByDescending...FirstOrDefault, running each one 10million times. On my PC the former takes around 5980ms, and the latter around 8500ms. If I jumble the order of the PlayerHands as they're added to the list a bit then the former comes in around 6150ms and the latter 8600ms. Seems if the list is already well ordered (which in my case it should be) then OrderBy...LastOrDefault is around 30% faster.

Comment: @Slugsie well i dont know how you measured. Performance tests are tricky, i suggest [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). I dont think that it matters how the list is ordered because if you use OrderBy/...Descending all items will be re-ordered. The LastOrDefault needs to check all items afterwards as opposed to FirstOrDefault which returns the result on the first match.

Answer (score 4):

Summarizing a few points,

- the number of rounds is finite (otherwise a really long game!). This observation is important when we talk about reversing below.
- rounds are already sorted in ascending order (per the comments), so actual round number *doesn't matter*
- if we sum backwards, we don't have to scan the whole list

So, we can come up with an implementation that is **O(1)** space (in-place, no allocations) and **O(n)** time (linear, less than the size of the list when there's a reset).

**Using MoreLinq**

```
var score = hands.ReverseInPlace().TakeUntil(x => x.Reset).Sum(x => x.Score);
```

Where `ReverseInPlace()` iterates in reverse order in place, and [MoreEnumerable.TakeUntil()](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/TakeUntil.cs) takes up to and including the round that has a true value for `Reset` or end of sequence.

`ReverseInPlace` would be an extension method (you could generalize to `IEnumerable<>` if you wanted).

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ReverseInPlace<T>(this IList<T> source)
    {
        // add guard checks here, then do...
        for (int i=source.Length-1; i != -1; --i)
            yield return source[i];
    }
}
```

**Not using MoreLinq**

You could create a `TakeInReverseUntil`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeInReverseUntil<T>(this IList<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    // add guard checks here, then do...
    for (int i=source.Length-1; i != -1; --i)
    {
        yield return source[i];
        if (predicate(source[i]) yield break;
    }
}
```

giving you the simplified call

```
var score = hands.TakeInReverseUntil(x => x.Reset).Sum(x => x.Score);
```

NOTE: [Enumerable.Reverse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=net-5.0) allocates a buffer, so is **O(n)** space, and is why I rolled my own `ReverseInPlace` instead for this answer.

Comment: Thanks for an in depth explanation and answer. I'm having a problem with the extension methods though, they both generate compilation errors on the generic T. Is this something that has changed in .Net Core 5 (which I am using).

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can see here is to simply change your check for the last reset round a bit and combine both statements:

```
public int GetPlayerScore()
{
    // selects the highest Round if Reset == true or 1 by default
    var lastResetRound = PlayerHands.Max(hand => hand.Reset ? hand.Round : 1);

    return PlayerHands.Where(t => t.Round >= lastResetRound.Round).Sum(t => t.Score);
    
    // or all toghether like this:
    return PlayerHands.Where(t => t.Round >= PlayerHands.Max(hand => hand.Reset ? hand.Round : 1)).Sum(t => t.Score);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution that satisfies the requirement of a single LINQ statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you used MoreLinq's `TakeUntil()` then you could do something like:

```
PlayerHands
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Round)
    .TakeUntil(x => x.Reset)
    .Sum(x => x.Score);
```

Edit: formatting & simplified bool conditional per @PrasadTelkikar

Comment: That's really missing in standard LINQ +1 ([here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/TakeUntil.cs)'s the source if you just want this method)

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware of MoreLinq, but that's certainly a useful extension method.

Answer (score 1):

I like the morelinq `TakeUntil` most which others have shown, missing it in the standard library.

I've tried to do it without creating new extension methods(cheating) and without morelinq. Following works, but is not as readable and also requires an ordered list(which is the case acc. to your comments).

```
return PlayerHands
    .TakeLast(PlayerHands.Count + 1 - (PlayerHands.FindLast(x => x.Reset)?.Round ?? 1))
    .Sum(x => x.Score);
```

Maybe someone finds a way to simplify the count-calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right in that it's a little unreadable. However it does satisfy the 'single line of LINQ' requirement.